# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to int

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Declare @count nvarchar(max)

```
set @count ='select COUNT(*) from '+ @tablename+''

if( @count =0 )
begin 
  print 'fail'
end
else
begin
  print 'success'
end
end
```

the @count variable is not getting the value 0. it shows the error as

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'select COUNT(*) from tablename' to data type int.

Comment: This does not work because `@COUNT` is varchar with value `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxx`, which is not a valid number :). Use dynamic SQL as described in answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @count int

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @CountOUT = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tablename;
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@CountOUT int OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @CountOUT=@count OUTPUT;

SELECT @count;
```

Comment: but will you clear me about these two lines . 'OUTPUT'

SET @ParmDefinition =   N'@CountOUT int OUTPUT';

and  @CountOUT=@count OUTPUT;

Comment: sp_executesql takes a list of parameters, this is defined in the variable @ParmDefinition here. Output means the variable if 'filled' with data in the query and can be used when the query is finished.

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @Count INTEGER
DECLARE @nSQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @nSQL = 'SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tablename
EXECUTE sp_executesql @nSQL, N'@Count INTEGER OUT', @Count OUT

-- Now check @Count
```

Be extra careful with dynamic sql like this, as you open yourself up to sql injection. So make sure @tablename is sanitized.

One check to be safe would be something like this, by making sure the table exists using a parameterised query before attempting the dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @Count INTEGER
DECLARE @nSQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @nSQL = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName) 
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tablename + '
ELSE
    SELECT @Count = -1'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @nSQL, N'@TableName NVARCHAR(128), @Count INTEGER OUT', @TableName, @Count OUT
```

If @Count then comes out at -1, you know it's because the tablename is invalid

**Edit:**
Reference to sp_executesql is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Check out Erland's standard article on [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). You're also a "victim" of [Data Type Precedences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring `@count` as an `int`:

```
DECLARE @count AS INT
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM YourTable
```

The problem is that if you do

```
SELECT @countAsString = 'SELECT ...'
```

then @countAsString (being a string) will not hold the result of the query, but the string itself.

Use `EXEC` to actually execute a dynamically created query.

Comment: ya i have tried that , same problem im getting

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int